# Impute NA values by pairs group present in column

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
label  id_row ID    Well  WT_group_1 WT_group_2 WT_group_3 WT_group_4 
<chr>   <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 well_1 169 PBS H1 2728. 2521 2360. 2670
2 well_2 361 PBS H1 2688 2534 2418 NA
3 well_3 553 PBS H1 3221 3320.5 2835 3247
4 well_4 745 PBS H1 2838 3362 2832. 2975
5 well_5 937 PBS H1 2857 2654 NA 2637
6 well_6 1129 PBS H1 2834 2678 2287 2713
7 well_7 1189 PBS B7 2374 2625 2444 2622
```

The rows `well_1-well_2, well_3-well_4, well_5-well_6`, are related. However, for `well_7` is alone, so I don't need to relate that one with any rows if I have NA values there.

I need to replace the NA with the value of rows that are related. For example:

```
well_1 2670
well_2 NA
after the operation:
well_1 2670
well_2 2670
or 
for well_4 and 5:
well_4 2832.
well_5 NA
after the operation: 
well_4 2832.
well_5 2832.
```

I was trying to perform this operation with this:

```
pbs_in_v2 %>%
    group_by(label) %>%
    fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
    ungroup()
```

However, using this idea involved `group_by`, when I need to do it with specific conditions:

```
well_1-well_2, well_3-well_4, well_5-well_6 and for well_7, leave it like that.
```

I think that performing an `if_else` could be good for this. However, how can I perform my goal if I need to use an if?

Is there a way to perform the task with my main idea, that involved `group_by` and `fill`

Any idea?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include reproducible data?

Comment: @Someone_1313  `group_by()` and `fill()` should work, so long as you do this grouping by a separate variable.  Something like `temp` in `pbs_in_v2 %>% mutate(temp = stringr::str_match(c("well_1", "well_2"), "well_(\\d+)"), temp = as.integer(temp[, 2]), temp = floor((temp + 1) / 2))`.  Here `temp` will read "`1`" for `well_1` and `well_2`, then "`2`" for `well_3` and `well_4`, then "`3`" for `well_5` and `well_6`, and finally "`4`" for `well_7`.  You can then continue the workflow with `... %>% group_by(temp) %>% fill(starts_with("WT"), .direction = "downup") %>% ungroup() %>% select(!temp)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group_by every two rows I think you can get your desired outcome, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "label  id_row ID    Well  `WT_group_1` `WT_group_2` `WT_group_3`
well_1    169 PBS   H1                   2728.              2360.              2670
well_2    361 PBS   H1                   2688               2418               NA
well_3    553 PBS   H1                   3221               2835               3247
well_4    745 PBS   H1                   2838               2832.              2975
well_5    937 PBS   H1                   2857               NA               2637
well_6   1129 PBS   H1                   2834               2287               2713
well_7   1189 PBS   B7                    2374              2444               NA",
header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = rep(1:nrow(.), each = 2)[1:nrow(.)]) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("WT"), ~vctrs::vec_fill_missing(.x, direction = "downup"))) %>%
  select(-grp)
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `grp`
#> # A tibble: 7 × 8
#> # Groups:   grp [4]
#>     grp label  id_row ID    Well  X.WT_group_1. X.WT_group_2. X.WT_group_3.
#>   <int> <chr>   <int> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <int>
#> 1     1 well_1    169 PBS   H1             2728          2360          2670
#> 2     1 well_2    361 PBS   H1             2688          2418          2670
#> 3     2 well_3    553 PBS   H1             3221          2835          3247
#> 4     2 well_4    745 PBS   H1             2838          2832          2975
#> 5     3 well_5    937 PBS   H1             2857          2287          2637
#> 6     3 well_6   1129 PBS   H1             2834          2287          2713
#> 7     4 well_7   1189 PBS   B7             2374          2444            NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

(I added NA to row 7 to show that it doesn't get replaced; would this approach work with your actual data?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zoo::nalocf0` here, and iterate through the rows using `apply`.

```
colpairs <- c("WT_group_1", "WT_group_2")

df[colpairs] <- t(apply(df[colpairs], 1, zoo::na.locf0))
```

Output:

```
   label id_row  ID Well WT_group_1 WT_group_2 WT_group_3
1 well_1    169 PBS   H1       2728       2360       2670
2 well_2    361 PBS   H1       2688       2418         NA
3 well_3    553 PBS   H1       3221       2835       3247
4 well_4    745 PBS   H1       2838       2832       2975
5 well_5    937 PBS   H1       2857       2857       2637
6 well_6   1129 PBS   H1       2834       2287       2713
7 well_7   1189 PBS   B7       2374       2444       2622
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "label  id_row ID    Well  WT_group_1 WT_group_2 WT_group_3
1 well_1    169 PBS   H1                   2728              2360              2670
2 well_2    361 PBS   H1                   2688               2418               NA
3 well_3    553 PBS   H1                   3221               2835               3247
4 well_4    745 PBS   H1                   2838               2832              2975
5 well_5    937 PBS   H1                   2857               NA               2637
6 well_6   1129 PBS   H1                   2834               2287               2713
7 well_7   1189 PBS   B7                    2374              2444               2622", h = TRUE)
```